# TeXstudio-2.6.6 loading of dictionary failed; hyph_en_US.dic file missing

Tags: texstudio, dictionaries

I have upgraded to TeXStudio 2.6.6 via the package manager in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS since the one in the repository was way too old. However, when I launch the application and try to open a file or check Latex installation an error box appears as I added here. Furthermore, when I click OK the system crashes and I cannot open the terminal or close TeXStudio leaving me with no choice but to restart the computer by holding the power button. I have tried reinstalling and uninstalling multiple times with no solution and would greatly appreciate any help and suggestions provided.

EDIT: The problem is solved I found a dictionary with featuring two files one with .aff extension and the other with .dic extension. However, I am still puzzled about how a missing dictionary in a program can crash the whole system. 
Thanks in advance

[image: Error message]

Answer (score 1):

That is rather easy to fix. Download this file from here:
http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/american-british-canadian-spelling-hyphen-thesaurus-dictionaries/releases/3.0/kpp-american-english-dictionary-797865-words-list.oxt
It has an .oxt extension but is actually an archive that can be opened with "ark" or any other archive program.
You will find both files in there,extract them and put them into /usr/share/hyphen. 
Please make sure that both files belong to "root". So you may need to do a 
"sudo chown root hyph_en_US.aff" and ""sudo chown root hyph_en_US.dic".
That should do the trick.
Have you checked the permissions for both files ? I remember that TexStudio is quite picky ? Open a console and try "ls -l /usr/share/hyphen" and see that the files belong to root.
Alternatively open TexStudio. Go to "Options/Configure" and check in "General" the path to the dictionary. Maybe you have a different setting in there that causes the crash !?
Edit 15:58: Just realized that I am already on TexStudio 2.6.6. My dictionary path points to /usr/share/texstudio and it's working fine.

Comment: I still get the error although I extracted all the files and replaced the prior ones with the new ones.